# VSTS Archive Files Task Cannot Find Build Output for Nested Project

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I have a massive solution of 41 projects consisting of the following:

- Shared domain models and entities
- 4 Windows Services
- MVC4 project (upgraded to MVC5) with a publish profile.

The idea is that once VSTS builds the solution and runs the publish profile - the output of each relevant project will be zipped up and put in the drop folder effectively creating 5 zip files for the build - 1 for the web project, and 4 for the windows services.

The publish profile for the MVC projects outputs the compiled binaries to a "deploy" folder. I have no problem using an archive task and copying the files from the "deploy" folder (which is a child of the root directory of the repo) to the web.zip file in the drop folder.

However - when I try to zip the contents of the bin/Release for each one of the windows services - the Archive Files task of the build definition blows up stating that "The system cannot find the file specified."

Any ideas? I am stuck.

I also forgot to mention that the Build Solution (Visual Studio Build) task builds and completes perfectly fine.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the output location of your Build Solution Task?

Comment: I am running a new build to verify your suggestion - but I think the issue is that the folder it's looking at `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Services\WindowsService1\bin\Release` doesn't exist because the solution is being built with /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 switches to MSBuild (i.e. it is built in debug mode). Therefore - the output of the project goes to `bin\Debug` instead of `bin\Release`.